# Questions regarding creating bootable USB

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, mac

I'm trying to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu for installing Ubuntu on my Mac with Dual Boot. I have 2 questions. I am a complete noob. I'm sorry if these questions sound too basic or downright stupid.

First question is: when erasing my USB to filesystem format FAT32 (MS-DOS) and partition scheme GUID Partition Map (which can be done using Disk Utility GUI or on terminal with commands: diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 UBUNTU GPT disk4), and after erasing so, when viewing the disks using diskutil list, I see that the volume (for me, disk4s2) with name UBUNTU has Microsoft Basic Data as Type. But I saw on Wiki that Microsoft Basic Data is basically equivalent to MBR, which I don't want (I want GPT). Why is this, since I made sure to specify scheme to be GPT? Does it matter? For disk identifier disk4, the Type is Guid Partition scheme. How can the volume have a different scheme from its parent disk?

The second question is: if I am not interested in booting from USB but only interested in downloading the Ubuntu to my Mac, do I need a bootable Ubuntu USB? Can I not just have ISO file on it?

Comment: Microsoft basic data just means it is NTFS or FAT32. And installer flash drive needs to be FAT32 with boot flag to boot as live installer. You cannot just download ISO and boot it from UEFI. If you have grub installed, there is an advanced way (loopmount) to boot an ISO.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.